# Can using a IP-address-sensitive view counter carry too much workload for MYSQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm pretty sure it's not much of a problem for 10,000 MYSQL rows, but what if we have hundreds of thousands, or even millions of rows?

Someone might tell me that cookies could solve the problem, but since I'm a rookie programmer, I figure that using cookies might raise more problem than it solves problems.

Is there any alternative? Or should I stick to non-IP-sensitive counter? In my application, this counter is only viewable by the seller of an item, not the users, some of whom might want to play around with the counter and refresh many times. So if they don't see a counter, they wont play around with refreshing.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP addresses are basically integers.

Store them as integers and use index on the corresponding column - queries are going to be very fast that way. Just keep in mind that ipv6 addresses are too large for 32 bit integers, so you might want to consider using varchar(16) instead and store binary representations of your ip addresses.

Concerning performance of your application, in my opinion, it is always good to use some kind of a caching system for this kind of statistics. For example regenerate your statistics only if, certain time interval has passed.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I didn't expect IP addresses to be integers since there are dots in them. Should the caching system be done on the PHP side or the MYSQL side? Thanks a lot, regards

Comment: Cache with PHP - execute mysql query only if last query was made for example 30 or more minutes ago. Store your results and query time in the file and generate new file only if needed. You can also go with mixed approach and create separate mysql table to hold caching information. In order to convert your ip addresses to numeric representation check php function ip2long and for binary check inet_pton.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways of approaching this. One way would be to have a log of item_id, ip_address and date with a unique index across all three columns. Then do an `INSERT IGNORE` into the table -

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`view_log` (
  `item_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`, `ip_address`, `date`)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO view_log ($item_id, INET_ATON('$ip_address'), CURRENT_DATE);
```

Note: this will only work for IPv4. To support IPv6 you will need to use a different method for storing the IP addresses.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I looked up the "INSERT IGNORE" command on google, but I don't understand exactly what it's being used for in the case of a counter. What is its purpose? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The idea is simple. Because of the unique index across the three columns you will only get one entry per user per item per day. When trying to insert another row that is the same MySQL will throw a duplicate-key error. Using ignore just supresses the error and returns a warning instead.