# Best view count strategy

Tags: mysql, wordpress, optimization

I am currently storing each view in database with user IP, view date etc. But mine website has large number of hits and it is increasing the database locking time and decreasing performance.

I was thinking to save the counts in a file for 1 hour and then update the database but somebody told me that we don't use file operations for heavy load sites.

Please suggest me best strategy to do this.

Note: I don't need to count the unique views.

Comment: I think transactions may be good.

Comment: Is this for analytic purposes? If so, you might want to consider using a free service like Google Analytics or Jetpack for tracking views instead.

Comment: Should I consider using APC cache for caching the data first and then updating it into the database after some views... ?

Comment: Hey Mat, this is not for analytics purpose. We need to sort the posts based on the view counts. We have different sorting options like most viewed today, most viewed this week, most viewed this month etc.

Comment: What levels of site traffic do you need to deal with? How many unique page views do you receive per day?

Comment: It is around 3000 hits per hour and I guess there will be like 1000 unique page views a day.

Comment: That is a small amount of traffic. It certainly should not be causing you noticeable locking problems. It would be a good idea for you to add your existing code to your question.

Comment: [My previous response to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037806/can-using-a-ip-address-sensitive-view-counter-carry-too-much-workload-for-mysql/10038045#10038045)

Answer (score 1):

Your webservers logs will already be tracking much of this data for you.

What I'd suggest is rotating the logs once an hour and then have a scheduled job that produces the aggregate stats and stores them in the DB.

Comment: Seems cool. I don't have much knowledge about servers can you please tell me where I can find the webservers logs

Comment: What web server are you using and what OS?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem keeping and updating this information in MySQL directly. 3000 hits per hour means less than one query per second. Using InnoDB storage engine for this table should remove locking issues. However InnoDB has plenty of options and it needs to be configured properly in order to work efficiently - this is important.

Based on your comments I think the structure you are seeking would look something like:

```
id - page id
type - period length, could be 'day', 'week', 'month'
period - date when period starts, could be integer written as YYYYMMDD or YYYYMM 
       - depending on the contents of 'type' field
count - hit count for a url over given period
```

The primary key would be `(type, period, id)`. Also indexes on `(id, period)` and on `(type, period, count)` for efficient:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ... 
WHERE type='week' 
  and period = 20120409 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

When page is created, insert records for each period with count = 0. When page gets a hit, run a simple update:

```
UPDATE table 
SET count = count + 1 
WHERE id = $page_id 
  AND period IN (201204, 20120409)
```

It would update all three records for 'day', 'week' and 'month' statistics.

Comment: I am not storing the type of the view, instead am calculating the view type by date. 
Not even URL as ID is sufficient in my case.
But am updating database on each view.

Comment: Updating this information on each view shouldnt be a problem with only 1 page view per second.

Comment: And if you can use ID rather than URL, then url column wouldn't be necessary. Just 'id' carrying the page id value rather than auto increment would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a plugin that does this very effectively (though you'd have to work out using the data to sort posts and so on): BAW Post Views Count. It stores everything in postmeta, so it's easy to get to, and maintains daily and other totals in separate meta entries. I use it on several sites, with periods of 50,000 page views a day, and it doesn't slow anything down.